# как написать рандомайзер с input для дискорда бота?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

нужно чтобы по команде -randomize,бот запрашивал переменные, которые введет пользователь и затем по рандому одна из этих переменных отправилась в чат.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def randomize(ctx, *, variables):
    vars = variables.split(' ')
    random_choise = random.choice(variables)
    await ctx.send(random_choise)
```

**Коги**

```
@commands.command()
async def randomize(self, ctx, *, variables):
    vars = variables.split(' ')
    random_choise = random.choice(variables)
    await ctx.send(random_choise)
```

Comment: `vars` - объект питона. А вы используете имя объекта в качестве переменной.

Comment: Извините, писал быстро, не заметил, исправил